# iOS 9.3.5 Issue with Flexbox overlapping content?

Tags: ios, css, flexbox

I'm having an issue with areas of a website I'm in the middle of developing where I have used Flexbox for the layout. For those with an iOS9 device, I'd love if you could go to [www.sparkles-cakes-of-art.co.uk](http://www.sparkles-cakes-of-art.co.uk) and see the issues first hand. The pages in question are: The homepage, about page, and menu.

This issue doesn't happen on Android phones, or desktop.

Here are some screenshots of the issue if you do not have a device to see it first hand:

[Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B436C.png)

Here is the CSS that should be affecting it

```
.flex {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
}

.half {
  -webkit-box-flex: 50%;
      -ms-flex: 50%;
          flex: 50%;
}

.cake-images {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  margin:20px 0px;
}
```

Relevant HTML for the homepage issue. If I can find out what is wrong with this I should be able to figure out the other pages:

```
<section class="flex">
        <article class="half">
          <p>blah!</p>
        </article>
        <blockquote class="half main-quote">
          <img src="img/quote-in.png" class="quote-in"/>
          <p class="quote">blah</p>
          <cite class="cite">blah</cite>
          <img src="img/quote-out.png" class="quote-out"/>
        </blockquote>
</section>
<section class="flex cake-images">
        <div class="main-cake-img">
          <div class="hidden-hover">
            <h2>Weddings</h2>
          </div>
          <a href="gallery#weddings">
            <img src="img/cake-01.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-cake-img">
          <div class="hidden-hover">
            <h2>Birthdays</h2>
          </div>
          <a href="gallery#birthdays">
            <img src="img/cake-02.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-cake-img">
          <div class="hidden-hover">
            <h2>Simplicity Offer</h2>
          </div>
          <a href="gallery#offer">
            <img src="img/cake-03.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
  </section>
```

Sorry I can't post more screenshots because of the rep limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

In the media query for phone devices I had this:

```
.half {
  flex: 100%;
}
```

I thought this would make the element go to 100% width, so as to only have 1 column. This will break on iOS Safari. Instead use `flex: 0 0 0;` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: This led me to the correct answer, which for me was changing `flex: 1 1 0%` to `flex: 1 1 0px`. For some reason iOS 9 balks at the `0%` at the end, which is annoying because I used `0%` precisely because of [this IE flexbox bug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-4).